# Getting cookie in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, cookies

I can get cookie in JSP like this:

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
if (cookies != null) {
    for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
        //work with cookies
    }
}
```

But I wonder if I can get it with jsp:useBean (or something else)?
May be like this:

```
<jsp:useBean id="myCookie" class="javax.servlet.http.Cookie" scope="request" beanName="cookieName"/>
...
<div class="${myCookie.value == "true" ? "class1" : "class2"}"></div>
```

Thx for your answers!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

use jsp  expression language it has implicit map of cookies. may be it can resolve your issue.

```
${cookie['name']}
```

Comment: Thx a lot. Also I found that I can use `${cookie.myCookieName}`.

Comment: For information only this doesn't seem to work if the JSP is served via Spring MVC

Comment: its not possible i have worked with spring ... it works. there should be any other issue .  can u share whatever u have done to test this .

Answer (score 2):

hope this one could help you to get name and value of your cookie

```
${cookie['cookiename'].getName()}
${cookie['cookiename'].getValue()}
```

OR

```
${cookie.cookiename.getName()}
${cookie.cookiename.getValue()}
```

OR

```
${cookie.<cookiename>.name}
${cookie.<cookiename>.value}
```