# retrieve a cookie in javascript code of a jsp page

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, cookies

I am trying to retrieve a cookie from a spring controller to a javascript code of a jsp page. This is the controller code

```
@CookieValue(required = true) String data) {
System.out.println("this is the sound cookie value>>>>>> " + data); //this prints the xyz cookie value to the console
```

Now in my javascript of a jsp page I am trying to retrieve the cookie this way

```
var cokdata= "${cookie['data']}";
        console.log("value>>>>>>> "+cokdata); //it returns nothing
```

Please how can I retrieve the cookie value in a javascript code of a jsp page

Comment: I don't know this annotation, but this is probably the problem, the EL is correct (add the full code please of this method)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730362/get-cookie-by-name

Comment: @Senthilnathan Look at this one ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19116040/getting-cookie-in-jsp the get is correct !

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using jQuery, you could use `$.cookie('data')` to retrieve the cookie as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-do-i-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery).

Note that cookies are just another header with name **Cookie** and values will be your key:pair cookie contents. For example in this case the cookie header be `Cookie:data=data_contents,cookie2:cookie2_contents,cookie3:cookie3_contents`